# How to use a dynamic dropdown created from a database to build a MySQL Query

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have built a dropdown list using PHP to show all the Unique names in my Table. I want to use that dropdown list to then use the selected value to create a MySQL Statement Dynamically.

Select * From iot_sensors WHERE Sensor_ID = ['USE the DROPDOWN MENU TO SELECT A NAME']

```
$select2 = "SELECT DISTINCT Sensor_ID FROM iot_sensors;";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $select2);
$counter2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

echo "<select name ='Sensor Names'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    echo "<option value ='".$row['Sensor_ID']."'>".$row['Sensor_ID']."   </option>";
}
    $dynamic_query = "SELECT * FROM iot_sensors WHERE Sensor_ID = ['option value']";
echo "</select>";
```

I understand usually if I had manually populated the dropdown menu all I would have to do is call the option value but here the option value is on there for HTML rendering purposes.

Answer (score 0):

First some warnings:

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

---

First, do not use names with spaces for HTML elements:

```
echo "<select name ='Sensor_Names'>";
```

Once selected and submitted (without knowing what your form `method=` is) the item will be in the `$_REQUEST` array:

```
$sensor_name = $_REQUEST['Sensor_Names'];
$dynamic_query = "SELECT * FROM iot_sensors WHERE Sensor_ID = '$sensor_name'";
```